# How do I get this to achieve the same padding?

Tags: css, wordpress

To start, please visit my website to show you what I mean: https://www.--

The content resizes as I want it to do, when going from desktop to mobile. But when on mobile, the recent slideshow (North Face article) I added doesn't have padding from the header-title, like all the other images do. How do I solve this?

Comment: It is better to supply us with a working example (for example a JSFiddle) so if your website ever changes this question can still be usefull for others.

Comment: I wish I knew how to, but I think this is dependent on my whole theme and it's something in there I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have here is that all yout other images are inside a `<p>` tag that have `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Your last post image is not inside a `<p>` tag so there is not the space with the post title in mobile.

You can add the margin-top to your last post slider only on mobile with media query.

```
 @media screen and (max-width:480px){
        #metaslider_container_506{
            margin-top:10px;
    }
}
```

Be careful when you will add an other post with a slider, the problem will come back, maybe you can add the `margin` to a class that will be on all the sliders, maybe on :

```
 @media screen and (max-width:480px){
            .metaslider .flexslider{
                margin-top:10px;
        }
    }
```

Like so, the problem will not come back with other post that have slider.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `margin-top` value to `metaslider_container_506` like this:

```
<div id="metaslider_container_506" style="margin-top:10px;">
```

Comment: Yes, this could have been the solution, but I want it to be bound to the header-section when not in mobile, like all the other pictures are.